# Serving django static files to Heroku

Tags: django, heroku

I know there are other similar questions but solutions are not working for me, I did try Heroku's django settings suggestion as well but still no luck.

At first no images/videos showed, I eventaully moved static folder around to get it to work.

Now Images and videos display fine on my Heroku site on the general pages but my search result images still do not display.

Update:
These images are just pictures of products. They are like any other images that are working on the site. They are static images pre-loaded to the folder they are held in, called 'products'. The only difference is the path is not directly called in the html. What I mean is other images are called like `"{% static 'assets/images/logo/logo_default1.png' %}"` Where the search results are called like `"{{ result.object.photo.url }}"`

Here is my setting file:

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'


STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "public/static"))


STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "mysite/static"),
    ) 
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "public/media"))
```

Here is my search page html:

```
<br></br>
            {% for result in page.object_list %}
         <div class="col-md-9">
         <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-5">
            <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="shop-item-slider">
            <ul class="bxslider">
               <li>
                 <img src="{{ result.object.photo.url }}" alt="img-theme">
               </li>
               <li>
                  <!--<img src="{% static 'assets/images/logo/logo_default1.png' %}" alt="hi">-->
                </li>
            </ul>
           </div>
```

**Note this all works fine locally, it is just on Heroku search images do not show for my search results.

I know it has to do with the static settings but not really sure what needs to change, again I have added the folder of images to the static asset folder with the other images that do work but still nothing.

Comment: You'll need to give more information. What are these images? Are they being uploaded by users? Where are you storing them? What are your MEDIA_* settings?

Comment: Sorry, I made update, the images are the same as the other images they are just in a different folder and not directly called in the html. What I mean is other images are called like "{% static 'assets/images/logo/logo_default1.png' %}"  Where the search results are called like "{{ result.object.photo.url }}"

Comment: But if they are coming from a model attribute, that means they are user-uploaded files referenced by an ImageField, no?

Comment: Well right, sorry for the confusion, but the images are just loaded to a folder in the static/asset folder like the other images. The portion of the model you are referring to I have like this: photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='products', null=True)
    url = models.URLField()             ***Again works perfectly fine locally just not on heroku

Comment: Except that they are not, because they are user-uploaded. Which means they are not included in your deployed code. Which means they cannot be stored in Heroku because the file system is ephemeral and per-dyno.

Comment: So how is this supposed to work then, images have to be stored in like AWS or something and static settings point there?